# Apple ID verification process not accepting my ID and/or password

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id

I have an iPhone 6 and during the last 2 months I see the *Apple ID verification* message. After I input my ID and password the iPhone won't accept it. I also get the same message with regard to iTunes sign in, and the same error message appears or an *iCloud cannot be accessed. Review your account information in settings* message.

Could someone please help me? I really don't know how can I solve this problem and update my application.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! It's possible that the entered password is incorrect. Try logging into icloud.com on a computer.

Comment: I have worked with this password before,but know it dose not work,do you think maybe someone hacked it?

Comment: I'd suggest you go to icloud.com on computer and try logging in. If you are unable to login, attempt to reset your password. If you are concerned about someone stealing your password, you can enable two factor authentication after getting access to your account.

Comment: I tried that site but I was unable to login.

Comment: Try recovering your password: https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid

Comment: i have done it and reset my password  but any massage does not com to my email

Comment: Can you try using a browser on another device and going to https://appleId.apple.com and let us know if that works.